# Is there a word for a place where things are stored temporarily?

Tags: british-english, single-word-requests

I'm not sure I can elaborate much more than what you already know from the title of this question - I need a word that means, or almost means, 'temporary storage space'.

Is there a word for a place where things are stored temporarily?

Comment: For programming and related contexts, a ***scratchpad***. Some had also written *parking spot* (or *space*), but I can't remember the username and they deleted their comment.

Comment: What kind of things? Furniture, data, nuclear waste, cars?

Comment: @Keepthesemind All/any of the above

Comment: The word is usually specific to the thing: locker, mortuary, pillow tank.

Comment: @Drew Could you make an answer for this with a reason?

Comment: **Staging Area** works in some contexts.

Answer (score 1):

**Cache**

> a hidden store of things, or the place where they are kept:
>
> an arms cache
>
> a cache of explosives/weapons/drugs

http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/cache

http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/cache

> A store of things that may be **required in the future**, which can be retrieved rapidly, protected or hidden in some way.

https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/cache

**Bank** [of something]

> A bank of something, such as blood or human organs for medical use, is a place that stores these things **for later use**:
>
> a blood bank
>
> a sperm bank

http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/bank?a=british

> A safe and guaranteed place of storage for and **retrieval** of important items or goods.
>
> blood bank; sperm bank; data bank‎

https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/bank

Comment: Although one can hardly envision storing many things permanently, there is no reference to the temporary (I assume less than a year, say) qualification OP imposes, in your answers.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I've boldly marked such references.

Comment: 'required in the future' / 'for later use' / 'retrieval' do not impose a maximum time constraint. As I pointed out, 'temporary storage' needs [Collins's second sense](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/temporary) here '2. lasting only a short time; transitory' as storage itself means putting aside for future use. {[AHDEL](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/store) _store_ 2. A stock or supply reserved for future use:}

Answer (score 0):

There're places to put things for security. There're places to put things you'll never want to see again. There're places to put things to keep them in optimal conditions so they remain hot, or cool. There're places to put things out of sight and other places to be on display. But, the things I wanna be able to lay my hands on impromptu and immediately are in my ***stash***.

Comment: 'Stash' is at least as good an answer as 'cache' and 'bank'...but you haven't provided any support for it (examples where it's used with the meaning requested, dictionaries where it's defined with that meaning, etc.), nor said why you think it means "stored **temporarily**" (where 'temporarily' must add meaning to 'stored').

Comment: Upvoted to counter the undeserved downvote.